# Drone that can send live camera footage, GPS coordinates and maybe IMU readings to a remote PC

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, recommendations

I need to acquire a drone for my dissertation project. The main requirement is to be able to transmit camera footage to a remote PC for processing. If possible, it would also help to send GPS coordinates and potentially IMU readings.

The main question is if there are any commercial drones that satisfy the above requirements or am I better off building one from scratch and if so, what components (flight controller especially) should I look for?
I know there are multiple good flight controllers like the Pixhawk series, but I also do not want to invest more than its necessary.

Budget: at most 500 eur with the mention that it can go a little higher if really needed.

Comment: For the price, see if you can pick up a used DJI Phantom 4 Pro.  The mobile apps can stream via RTMP, or you can put an HDMI board into the controller (if it doesn't already have it) and capture that video and send out.